# Tensorflow-directml vs tensorflow-CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently starting to study CNN in Python with Tensorflow. I do understand that Tensorflow uses CUDA, so I instead tried using Tensorflow-directml because I'm using an AMD gpu (RX 580 and I3 10100f CPU). I tried to build a basic model for an object detection using CIFAR-10 dataset with this model:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D( 32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,3) ) )
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D( (2,2) ))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(layers.Conv2D( 64, (3,3), activation='relu' ) )
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D( (2,2) ))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(layers.Conv2D( 128, (3,3), activation='relu' ) )
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D( (2,2) ))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
```

Note: processed with Adam optimizer with default learning rate.

My question is not about what is the proper model, but instead why significant performance where tensorflow-CPU  is performing faster than tensorflow-directml. It takes ~3 mins with my CPU for 1 epoch with 50000 training data where as directml took ~13 mins for 1 epoch with 50000 training data. What seems to cause this performance difference and on what cases should i use my GPU or CPU?

Answer (score 2):

Its probably because you have a more modern cpu than gpu. I ran a CNN on my cpu(R5 5500) and it was only a little bit slower than my gpu(Radeon RX 5600XT).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33183823)